# Merging two arrays by conditionally toggling which array's row should be used next

Tags: php, arrays, merge, conditional-statements, toggle

I've got two arrays with the same objects.
They are of the form:

```php
$arrayA = [
    ["sentence" => "Hello world",        "nextSpeaker" => 0],
    ["sentence" => "Hello world again",  "nextSpeaker" => 1],
    ["sentence" => "Hello world twice!", "nextSpeaker" => 1],
];

$arrayB = [
    ["sentence" => "Bye world",       "nextSpeaker" => 1],
    ["sentence" => "Bye world again", "nextSpeaker" => 0],
    ["sentence" => "Bye world twice", "nextSpeaker" => 0],
];
```

The effect that I want to achieve is, starting with Array A, to merge both arrays but have then in the correct order. So, if from array A, the `nextSpeaker` is 0, it should take the next result from `ArrayA`. If the `nextSpeaker` is 1, then it should take from `ArrayB` and then look at the next item from `ArrayB` to see if the next speaker is speaker 1. If not, it shuold look at `ArrayA` again.

I have tried to just merge both arrays, loop through the merged array and keeping track of the current key for the speaker0 and speaker1 arrays, but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Desired output:

```
[
    ['sentence' => 'Hello world',        'nextSpeaker' => 0],
    ['sentence' => 'Hello world again',  'nextSpeaker' => 1],
    ['sentence' => 'Bye world',          'nextSpeaker' => 1],
    ['sentence' => 'Hello world twice!', 'nextSpeaker' => 1],
    ['sentence' => 'Bye world again',    'nextSpeaker' => 0],
    ['sentence' => 'Bye world twice',    'nextSpeaker' => 0],
]
```

Comment: What should happen, if `nextSpeaker` is always 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using a while loop until both arrays are empty. Foreach over the first array with shifting first value off as long as the break condition matches, do the same for the seconds array.

**Warning!** This mutates and clears `$arrayA` and `$arrayB`. If you don't want it, make a copy first.

```
$arrayA = [
    ["sentence" => "Hello world", "nextSpeaker" => 0],
    ["sentence" => "Hello world again", "nextSpeaker" => 1],
    ["sentence" => "Hello world twice!", "nextSpeaker" => 1],
];

$arrayB = [
    ["sentence" => "Bye world", "nextSpeaker" => 1],
    ["sentence" => "Bye world again", "nextSpeaker" => 0],
    ["sentence" => "Bye world twice", "nextSpeaker" => 0],
];

$arrayC = [];

while ($arrayA || $arrayB) {
    foreach ($arrayA as $array) {
        $arrayC[] = array_shift($arrayA);
        if ($array['nextSpeaker'] == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($arrayB as $array) {
        $arrayC[] = array_shift($arrayB);
        if ($array['nextSpeaker'] == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

results in

```
[
    ['sentence' => 'Hello world',        'nextSpeaker' => 0],
    ['sentence' => 'Hello world again',  'nextSpeaker' => 1],
    ['sentence' => 'Bye world',          'nextSpeaker' => 1],
    ['sentence' => 'Hello world twice!', 'nextSpeaker' => 1],
    ['sentence' => 'Bye world again',    'nextSpeaker' => 0],
    ['sentence' => 'Bye world twice',    'nextSpeaker' => 0],
]
```

Comment: You don't need to change the array contents, and all those loops, conditions, etc. You can put the arrays inside an array (`$arrays = [$arrayA, $arrayB];`) and use the functions `current` (`$currentElement = current($arrays[$index])`) and `next`  (`next($arrays[$index])`) instead. The arrays have pointers for iterations.

Comment: @PedroAmaralCouto When I answer, I do my best to do it beginner friendly and readable as possible. The best solution is presented by mickmackusa what kind I would use my own code.

Comment: I think a solution that doesn't change the original arrays should be provided. Is `$index = $currentElement['nextSpeaker'];` less readable than `$pullFrom = $row['nextSpeaker'] ? 1 - $pullFrom : $pullFrom;`? Is `$currentElement = current($arrays[$index]);` harder to understand than `$arrays[0] && $arrays[1]` or `$arrayA || $arrayB`? Is `$merged []= $currentElement;` and `next($arrays[$index]);` hard to understand? Also, learning about some concepts might be important. `next` and `current` are used internally by `foreach`, and are required when implementing an `Interator`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @PedroAmaralCouto What?! This solution may not be the best and could be immutable as mentioned in the answer itself, but it does its job and is simple. Also your comment relates too heavy on other answers IMHO.

Comment: May you provide an immutable version? If someone needs to keep `$arrayA` or `$arrayB`, it would be useful.

Comment: No, because you can a) do a copy before as noted in the answer and b) as already said, @mickmackusa has a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

I find it most elegant to declare the two inputs into one master array, then conditionally toggle which array to access while shifting rows into the result.

When the loop is broken because one of the input arrays has become empty/exhausted, then merge any remaining rows from the other array into the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HMpgI))

```
$arrays = [$arrayA, $arrayB];
$pullFrom = 0;
$result = [];
while ($arrays[0] && $arrays[1]) {
    $result[] = $row = array_shift($arrays[$pullFrom]);
    $pullFrom = $row['nextSpeaker'] ? 1 - $pullFrom : $pullFrom;
}

var_export(array_merge($result, ...$arrays));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [PHP arrays iterators](https://brainbell.com/php/array-internal-pointers.html):

```php
reset($arrayA);
reset($arrayB);
$arrays = [$arrayA, $arrayB];
$index = 0;
$merged = [];
while ($currentElement = current($arrays[$index])) {
    $merged []= $currentElement;
    next($arrays[$index]);
    $index = $index === $currentElement['nextSpeaker'] ? 0 : 1;
}
```

`reset` might not be needed, if the arrays iterators were not changed.

If you don't like the `while ($currentElement = current($arrays[$index]))`, you can do this instead:

```php
$arrays = [$arrayA, $arrayB];
$index = 0;
$merged = [];
for (;;) {
    $currentElement = current($arrays[$index]);
    if (!$currentElement) {
        break;
    }
    $merged []= $currentElement;
    next($arrays[$index]);
    $index = $index === $currentElement['nextSpeaker'] ? 0 : 1;
}
```

If you don't trust the `for(;;)` loop, you can do:

```php
$length = count($arrayA) + count($arrayB);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
```